# Safe to use a Switching Voltage Regulator to power a Microsoft Surface Pro 4?

Tags: power-supply

Is it safe to use a switching voltage regulator to power a Microsoft Surface Pro 4? I'm specifically concerned with the ripple/noise that produced by this type of voltage converter.

[Voltage Step Up Converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J03PBW0)

Comment: You should post this question to the manufacturer.  EE.SE is not his volunteer application support.

Comment: Well, when you consider that the surface pro 4 is *supplied* with a switching power brick, I think it's safe to assume it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general yes. The Surface Pro 99.999% probably uses a switching regulator to charge in the first place. What you really want to know is how sensitive it is, or if that specific regulator will work okay. Quality of regulation is important. It depends on the switching frequency used, the quality of parts used. If you are going from mains to 12V dc you have much more to filter out than you do if you are going from dc to dc, or batteries stepping up. And your source and regulator should be able to handle the current needed, both peak and nominal, as well as how fast it may pull.

As mentioned, the first step is figuring out the actual noise or ripple your converter will produce compared to the original one. Then take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

In principle it is safe if the regulator output meets the requirements of the surface input. It does depend on the quality of the product though so it is impossible to give a yes or no answer without evaluating the product. You could buy one and stress test it by loading it with greater than your expected loads and switching the load on and off. Check the voltage with a scope and see if it goes out of specifications.